# C#, How to delete copy-pase with handlers

Tags: c#, optimization

Please say about "How optimally" rewrite this code without copy-paste.
Now I have two handlers with equivalent lambda handlers...
Sorry for more code and bad style ((

```
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, args) =>
    {
        try
        {
            res = (T)(object)args.Result;
            var cook = Regex.Matches(wc.ResponseHeaders.ToString(), "Set\\-Cookie:\\s*([\\w\\-_\\.]+\\s*=\\s*[^;]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);
            foreach (Match val in cook)
                cookies += val.Groups[1].Value.Trim() + "; ";
            isComplited = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            lastError = e.InnerException.Message;
        }
    };


    wc.UploadDataCompleted += (sender, args) =>
    {
        try
        {
            res = (T)(object)args.Result;
            var cook = Regex.Matches(wc.ResponseHeaders.ToString(), "Set\\-Cookie:\\s*([\\w\\-_\\.]+\\s*=\\s*[^;]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);
            foreach (Match val in cook)
                cookies += val.Groups[1].Value.Trim() + "; ";
            isComplited = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            lastError = e.InnerException.Message;
        }
    };
```

Comment: You need to read a few C# tutorials, e.g. http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/functions/

Comment: I'm not going to try and see where the differences are but instead of using the lambda expresssion, make a method, and call that method. twice.

Comment: this handlers has different type of "args"

Comment: I have colleagues who write such code and just do not care. It is good that you care! You are already better than them.

Comment: @user2601969 but if you are not using specific args fields, you can write `EventArgs` in method stub and everything works fine

Answer (score 3):

```
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, args) =>
{
    PerformAction(sender,args);
};


wc.UploadDataCompleted += (sender, args) =>
{
    PerformAction(sender,args);
};
```

Or shorter:

```
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += PerformAction;
wc.UploadDataCompleted += PerformAction;
```

create new method wich contains this code and run it instead of your doubled code

```
public void PerformAction(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
        try
        {
            res = (T)(object)args.Result;
            var cook = Regex.Matches(wc.ResponseHeaders.ToString(), "Set\\-Cookie:\\s*([\\w\\-_\\.]+\\s*=\\s*[^;]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);
            foreach (Match val in cook)
                cookies += val.Groups[1].Value.Trim() + "; ";
            isComplited = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            lastError = e.InnerException.Message;
        }
}
```

Comment: Or just `wc.DowloadStringCompleted += PerformAction`

Comment: @juharr I was just editing that :) thanks, I was 4 seconds faster :D